# how to link OpenGL with VC++

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2005

I am developing one game where I want to add OpenGL framework with VC++ 2005 express edition. But I dont know how to add OpenGL framework with VC++. So can any one guide me for this.

Please explain me in detail.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must link with opengl32.lib and potentially glu32.lib. The headers should already be provided with the [Platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235626(VS.80).aspx) (which needs to be downloaded separately, if you don't already have it).

If possible, you should consider upgrading to VS2008 Express, since it's free.

Comment: Thank You very much it works but I dont have platformSDk so I am searching for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a windowing toolkit before you can use opengl. GLUT is the easiest to learn/use for begining with opengl. Here is a guide to download GLUT and how to create an opengl project.

http://www.cecs.csulb.edu/~pnguyen/Using%20OpenGL%20in%20Visual%20Studio%202005.htm

You should have all of the opengl libs and headers already so you should only need to download glut.

Comment: Thank You very much it works but I dont have platformSDk so I am searching for that.....